# PowerShell: How to check which button is clicked

Tags: powershell, button, user-interface

I have a gui with some buttons to check some system informations. The routine is always the same, but I don't want to write it 5 times. How can I check which button the user has pressed?

For example:

```
Foreach ($server in $serverlist) {

   If ( (Test-Connection $server -Quiet -count 1) ) {

      If ($button1.clicked) {

         #Get OS Info

      }

      Else {}

      If ($button2.clicked) {

         #Get Disk Info

      }

      Else {}              


   Else {

      Write-Output "`r`n$server not available...`r`n" | Out-File c:\temp\error.txt

   }

   }

   Else {}

}

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('system.windows.forms'); [system.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::show('query complete')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than multiple `if($buttonWhatever.clicked)`, attach [an event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the button itself and make it do all the work.

```
$btnGetOSInfo.Add_Click(
{
# stuff for getting OS
}
)

$btnGetDiskInfo.Add_Click(
{
# stuff for getting Disk info
}
)
```